# Почему чтение файла осуществляется не с начала? JAVA

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\krist\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\access.log");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            //создаем BufferedReader с существующего FileReader для построчного считывания
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            // считаем сначала первую строку
            String line = reader.readLine();
            //String[] words = line.split(" ");
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                // считываем остальные строки в цикле
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Может что-то путаю, но покрайней мере вывод в консоль начинается в выделенного справа момента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль в IDEA не бесконечная и при выводе большого количества строк там остаются только последние N строк (точное значение N мне неизвестно). Именно это и наблюдается на скриншоте.